# how do I add autocomplete of | | for sublimetext?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

How do I add auto complete or word wrap of | | for sublime text 2 for Ruby editing?

Is it something to do with word wrap?

Comment: are you talking about snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Preferences -> Settings - User` and add the following:

```json
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "<",
        "selector": "text.html"
    },
    {
        "characters": "|",
        "selector": "source.ruby"
    },
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source"
    }
]
```

This will trigger autocomplete in HTML documents when you open a tag, in Ruby files when you open a `|foo bar|` block argument, and in any source code when you enter a `.` to access a method, function, or attribute.

Comment: thanks but what I'm looking for is much like how sublime does auto complete with parentheses(bracket) or curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

found my answer, just use the default key binding for auto-pair bracket and change the bracket to use ||  in User Keybind, for anyone interested in how to auto-pair || or add any auto pair in sublime text 2 or 3 try the following:

```
// Auto-pair block args
{ "keys": ["|"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "|$0|"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["|"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "|${0:$SELECTION}|"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["|"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\|", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Left Right.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\|$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\|", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I fixed your regexes, they were still matching `(` and `)` instead of `|` in the third and fourth binding commands :)